# Memory leak when Calls C# Windows API "properties"

Tags: c#, memory-leaks

When I found memory leak in my application, I use profiling tools to detect that the unmanaged memory is keep raising; Then I use binary search method to location the API which could cause the memory issue. This means if the API is called in the function context then memory issue exists; while if the API is commented in the code, the memory issue doesn't show up. Attached the code for your reference:

```
class Program
{

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Accelerometer acc = Accelerometer.GetDefault();
        if (acc == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("NULL instance received");
            return;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("acc created taking sample");
        var reading = acc.GetCurrentReading();
        if (reading == null)
        {

        }
        else
        {

        }
        acc.ReadingChanged += acc_ReadingChanged; ;
        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit");
        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    private static void acc_ReadingChanged(Accelerometer sender, AccelerometerReadingChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var reading = args.Reading;
        // below code is the place where memory leak happens 
        // actually nothing is done here
        // start
        foreach (var item in reading.Properties)
        {
        }
        // end
        double[] Data = new[] { reading.AccelerationX, reading.AccelerationY, reading.AccelerationZ };

        Console.WriteLine(Data[0].ToString() + Data[1].ToString()+Data[2].ToString());
    }
}
```

So is there any wrong with the code such as the usage of foreach or KeyPairValue ?API link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.sensors.accelerometerreading

Comment: Possibly.  [It is prerelease code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.sensors.accelerometer)

Comment: It is only ever a real leak when the code causes your program to fail with an OutOfMemoryException.  Seeing unmanaged memory usage grow is entirely normal, UWP code is unmanaged and the language projection uses COM to interop with it.  The Properties member is not cheap.  If this is the only thing your program ever does then the garbage collector does not nearly run often enough, so the RCW wrappers take up space for a while.  You could arbitrarily count the event callbacks and, say, every 1000th invocation call GC.Collect().  But surely the real issue is that you just didn't wait long enough.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for your response. The OutOfMemoryExcpetion is the first phenomenon when there are multiple sensors running at the highest sample rate (100 or 400 HZ). During the overnight test, OutOfMemoryExcpetion is thrown. So this memory leak is repeatable. I would like to follow your suggestion to call GC.Collect and see whether this issue still exists or not.